# Bash: Increment variable inside while loop and display the value outside the loop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, bash-scripting

Let's say if I have a code like this.

```bsh
var=0

while [ condition ] 
do
  ((var+=1))
done

echo $var
```

How can I increment `$var` inside the loop and display its value outside of it? Thanks

Let's say if the loop runs for 5 times, my `$var`, the output should be `5`. But now I only got `0` even if the loop runs for like 10 times. `$var` is just not incremented inside the loop.

Comment: `+-=` is not a valid operator; other than that the code looks ok. (Well, you should put double-quotes around most variable references, like `echo "$1"`, but that's not likely to be a problem in this case.) Can you give a complete example that shows the problem you're seeing? Note that you should trim it down to just the section necessary to show the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Check this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/385532/680869

Comment: I've edited my question. It was a typo. My apologies

Comment: I'm not able to duplicate the problem. I tested with `$var -lt 10` as the condition, and the loop ran ten times (as expected) and printed "10" (as expected). As I said before, please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Both...

```
cnt=0
while [ $cnt -lt 10 ]
do
  ((cnt++))
done
echo $cnt
```

...and...

```
cnt=0
while [ $cnt -lt 10 ]
do
  let cnt=cnt+1
done
echo $cnt
```

...work.

What `$SHELL` are you using?